# Use multiple keys to get the largest value from a hashtable

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
Record Key          Sequence Number Transportation Segment Number   Arrival Date
18010312076777      1               1                               01/16/2018
18010312076777      1               2                               01/17/2018
18010312076867      1               1                               01/16/2018
18010312076867      1               2                               01/17/2018
18010312078634      1               1                               01/16/2018
18010312078634      1               2                               01/18/2018
18010912098476      1               1                               1/10/2018
18010912098476      1               2                               1/10/2018
18010912098476      1               3                               1/11/2018
18010912098476      1               4                               1/11/2018
18010912099327      1               1                               01/16/2018
18010912099327      1               2                               01/17/2018
18010912101156      1               1                               01/16/2018
18010912101156      1               2                               01/17/2018
```

I have used the Import-Csv cmdlet to bring it in as a hashtable. This works fine.

I'm trying to create another hashtable based on the following logic: *For each unique Record Key and Sequence Number combination, return the largest Transportation Segment Number and its corresponding Arrival Date*

For example the first Record Key 18010312076777 is listed twice, both with the Sequence Number of 1 (although Sequence Number could be any value). The largest Transportation Segment Number is 2.

The Record Key 18010912098476 has four entries, but we're only interested in the entry that has Transportation Segment Number = 4. If this Record Key had an entry where Sequence Number was say 2, we would need to pull back the rows where Sequence Number = 1 *and* Sequence Number = 2.

So the new hashtable should contain:

```
Record Key          Sequence Number Transportation Segment Number   Arrival Date
18010312076777      1               2                               01/17/2018
18010312076867      1               2                               01/17/2018
18010312078634      1               2                               01/18/2018
18010912098476      1               4                               1/11/2018
18010912099327      1               2                               01/17/2018
18010912101156      1               2                               01/17/2018
```

I've written this code

```
function New-LastSegments {
  # For each unique Record-Key + Sequence number, return the largest Transportation Segment Number and the corresponding Arrival Date

  # Create a new hashtable
  $global:last_segment_reference = @{};

  # Get a list of unique record keys to search on
  $record_keys = $global:transeg_table | Select-Object "Record Key", "Sequence Number" -Unique | Out-String;

  # Step through the record keys
  $record_keys | ForEach-Object ({
     # New row
     $new_segment_reference = @{};

     # Get the last transportation segment number that matches our unique Record Key and Sequence Number
     $transportation_segment_number = $global:transeg_table |
      Where-Object ({$global:transeg_table.$('Record Key') -eq $_.$('Record Key')}) -and ({$global:transeg_table.$('Sequence Number') -eq $_.$('Sequence Number')}) | ForEach-Object $global:transeg_table.$('Transportation Segment Number') |  Select-Object -last 1

     $new_segment_reference | Add-Member -Name "Record Key" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.$('Record Key');
     $new_segment_reference | Add-Member -Name "Sequence Number" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.$('Sequence Number');
     $new_segment_reference | Add-Member -Name "Transportation Segment Number" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.$transportation_segment_number;
     # I think this needs to be set at the same time as the Transportation Segment Number
     $new_segment_reference | Add-Member -Name "Arrival Date" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.$('Arrival Date');

     # Add the new row to the new hashtable
     $global:last_segment_reference += $new_segment_reference;
 })
}
```

I'm getting

> "Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'and'."

and

> "The property 'Record Key' cannot be found on this object. Verify that
>   the property exists."

Can anyone help me with the logic and syntax to produce this hashtable? I've gotten other hashtables to work with just a single key but I'm running into difficulty with multiple keys.

Comment: You have typos in your Where-Object call. It should be something like Where-Object { ($global:transeg_table.'Record Key' -eq $_.'Record Key') -and ($global:transeg_table.'Sequence Number' -eq $_.'Sequence Number') }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've just sorted the table by the first three columns (`Record Key`, `Sequence Number`, and `Transportation Segment Number`) in ascending order (your example table is actually already sorted this way, but I chose not to make assumptions). Then I've grouped the table data based on `Record Key` and `Sequence Number`, and selected the last item in each group:

```
$groups = ($global:transeg_table | sort -Property "Record Key","Sequence Number","Transportation Segment Number" | Group-Object -Property "Record Key","Sequence Number")

foreach ($group in $groups) { $group.Group | select -last 1 }

Record Key     Sequence Number Transportation Segment Number Arrival Date
----------     --------------- ----------------------------- ------------
18010312076777 1               2                             01/17/2018
18010312076867 1               2                             01/17/2018
18010312078634 1               2                             01/18/2018
18010912098476 1               4                             1/11/2018
18010912099327 1               2                             01/17/2018
18010912101156 1               2                             01/17/2018
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution but it seems less complicated than what you have at the moment and it does work (assuming I've understood the problem correctly).